# Conversation state in Microsoft bot framework

Tags: bots, botframework

I want to know how long a conversation state will be there if we haven't added any expiry method in the bot framework. Did anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it's up to you.

Check out the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) for Managing state.

From the docs:

> The Bot Framework SDK includes some implementations for the storage
> layer:
>
> - Memory storage implements in-memory storage for testing purposes. In-memory data storage is intended for local testing only as this
>   storage is volatile and temporary. The data is cleared each time the
>   bot is restarted.
> - Azure Blob Storage connects to an Azure Blob Storage object database.
> - Azure Cosmos DB partitioned storage connects to a partitioned Cosmos DB NoSQL database.

(although it also states: The Cosmos DB storage class has been deprecated.)

Or you can write your own custom [storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-custom-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

What your question really comes down to is when does a [conversation expire](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-expire-conversation?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp).  This can be a function of the bot or the storage layer.

From the conversation expire link above:

> - User Interaction Expiration
>
> This type of expiring conversation is accomplished by adding a last
> accessed time property to the bot's conversation state. This property
> value is then compared to the current time within the activity handler
> before processing activities.
>
> - Storage Expiration
>
> Cosmos DB provides a Time To Live (TTL) feature that allows you to
> delete items automatically from a container after a certain time
> period. This can be configured from within the Azure portal or during
> container creation (using the language-specific Cosmos DB SDKs).
>
> The Bot Framework SDK doesn't expose a TTL configuration setting.
> However, container initialization can be overridden and the Cosmos DB
> SDK can be used to configure TTL prior to Bot Framework storage
> initialization.